# How to set table encoding in Liquibase changeset?

Tags: database, liquibase

How to set table encoding to utf8_danish_ci for Liquibase create table changeset ?

Comment: This feature would be database specific. You haven't stated which database you're using....

Answer (score 1):

I have to use row sql for this `<sql>ALTER TABLE`tablename`CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8</sql>`